# Is there a way to sync local redux store with remote data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am looking to create an application with local redux store. But I want the   store to sync frequently with a remote store over internet.

I'm looking for something like git or rsync that can solve conflicts and keep versions. Is there any library in react that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's many existing libraries for store persistence and syncing.  See the [Store Persistence](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store-persistence.md) and [Store#Synchronization](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#synchronization) sections of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links)

Comment: Thanks!! Among them pouch db seems interesting as it has the support of couchdb as backup.